# All titles to slide in on scroll - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop, foreach

So I'm writing some code where titles slide in from either the left or right side upon scrolling. I've used document.querySelector('subtitle-left) to select each individual title but how would you do this so ALL titles slide in upon scrolling with the same piece of code? Rather than writing the same thing out for one title. I understand that you may have to use a forEach loop - how would I write this for the below code?

```js
function slideInLeft() {
  var greenBox = document.querySelector('.subtitle-left');
  var greenPosition = greenBox.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var screenPosition = window.innerHeight / 1.2;

  if (greenPosition < screenPosition) {
    greenBox.classList.add('slide-in-left');
  }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', slideInLeft);
```

```css
.green-box-left {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 6vw;
  background: #daf4dc;
}

.subtitle-left {
  font-family: 'termina', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  transition: 1s all;
  left: 28%;
  margin-top: 9%;
  transform: translateX(-139%);
}

.slide-in-left {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="green-box-left">
  <h5 class="subtitle-left">HOMEPAGES</h5>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="green-box-left">
  <h5 class="subtitle-left">HOMEPAGES 2</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` will give you only first matching element, try with `querySelectorAll` thus you'll get all matching elements then you can iterate them and add class to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to add querySelectorAll to get all the instances of the class then rewrite your code a little to include the forEach loop as you already adhered to. You could try something similar to this:

```
  function slideInLeft() {
        var greenBox = document.querySelectorAll('.subtitle-left');
     
        greenBox.forEach(function(box) {

            var greenPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var screenPosition = window.innerHeight / 1.2;
  
        if (greenPosition < screenPosition) {
          box.classList.add('slide-in-left');
        }
       
});
} 
window.addEventListener('scroll', slideInLeft);
```